# How to make iOS open separate keychain files from macOS

Tags: keychain

I have separate keychain files on my Mac, but they are obviously not synced via iCloud. Are there any way to open them on iOS? Conversion to another format is viable, but free (both in beer and speech) solutions are preferred.

Comment: do you mean like export ?

Comment: Yes, but directly opening is preferred.

Comment: you mean like sharing (without iCloud)

Comment: I mean view and manage passwords in them on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Example ..

Steps to create .p12 file:

```
Run the Keychain Access Application on your Mac.
Select the login keychain from the top-left panel
Select key's
Right click and select Export Items...
Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format, and name the file “something.p12”
You will be prompted to create a password that is used when you attempt to import this key on another computer
Enter a password and save
```

Comment: There is no "Export Items..." menu item for items in separate keychain files.

Comment: @fossilet what is 'separate keychain files`

Comment: you press cmd + shift + n and create a new keychain file.